# Analytical testcase for 2D/3D anisotropic Diffusion (Heat Kernel)

Tags: convergence, diffusion, heat-transfer

I want to verify and compare different Discretizations of the anisotropic diffusion equation in 2D / 3D.

[image]

In order to both test the timestepping and the spatial discretisations I had a look at using the heat kernels as an analytical solution to diffusion equations. The one dimensional heat kernel ([wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_kernel)) looks like this:
$$
u(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}} e^{-x^2/4t}\
$$
and solves following diffusion equation of dimension $d$ analytically:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = -\Delta u
$$

The idea is that for an analytical solution I can verify my convergence both spatially and temporal. It is important in my case, that the diffusion is **anisotropic**, and might not be aligned with the underlying grids.

My **anisotropic** diffusion equation reads:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla (D \nabla u)
$$

In order to expand the analytical solution to my case, where the diffusion is not scalar and unity, but a full (symmetric positive definite) tensor D, I had a look at multivariate gaußian distributions ([wiki-link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution)).

My question is the following:

1. Is there somewhere in the literature a heat kernel for anisotropic (but homogeneous) diffusion which I can use to verify my numerics?

By analogy I would come up with something like:

$$
u(\vec{x},\vec{\mu},t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi~ |\mathbf{D}| t)^{d/2}} \exp \large(\frac{-(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})^{T} \mathbf{D}^{-1}(\vec{x}-\vec{\mu})}{4~|\mathbf{D}|~t}\large).
$$

2. Is the above equation a proper analytical solution of the anisotropic diffusion equation?

I am not sure if the exponent $d/2$ is correct for the $|D|$. I am aware that the question might touch both physics, and numerics, but I thought this might be useful to other people trying to verify their codes.

Any hints or help is appreciated!

Comment: I'd start by looking for a coordinate transformation (using the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $D$) which transforms your anisotropic diffusion into isotropic diffusion. Then you can transform the classical heat kernel solution back into the original anisotropic space. But I haven't worked out the details.

Comment: This may be a stupid comment, but have you thought about just manufacturing an analytical solution using the method of manufactured solutions? This is generally what I do for anisotropic equations...

Answer (score 1):

Since Laplacian is an elliptic operator you are looking for the Cholesky decomposition of the assumed constant diffusion matrix $D$:
$$D = LL^T$$

Therefore the parabolic equation may be written as:
$$\partial_t u=-\nabla^T(D\nabla u)=-(L^T\nabla)^T(L^T\nabla u)=-\tilde{\nabla}^T(\tilde{\nabla} u)=-\tilde{\nabla}^2u$$

Naming $\tilde{\nabla}=L^T\nabla$ and therefore $\tilde{x}=L^{-1}x$. This last PDE is totally decoupled (using Fourier transform and separation of variables).

The solution for the unnormalised heat kernel will be (using $\tilde{x}=L^{-1}x$):
$$\Phi=\prod_{n=1}^d\frac{\exp{(-\tilde{x}_n^2/(4t))}}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}=\frac{\exp{(-\tilde{x}^T\tilde{x}/(4t))}}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}}=\frac{\exp{(-x^TD^{-1}x/(4t))}}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}}$$

Comment: There is one step missing here in getting kernel in $x$ space. The solution involves a convolution so you have to transform the $d$-dimensional measure $d \tilde{x}$ to $dx$. In $x$-space the kernel becomes $\exp(-x^\top D^{-1}x/(4t))/(4\pi t |D|)^{d/2}$.